# Best way to represent MDX result in R

Tags: r, mdx

Newby to R so I'm wondering what is the best way to represent an MDX result in R language. We can assume 2 axis in MDX that results in something like :

The particularity of MDX is that the result as multiple header on both axis

```
                       2010    2010    2011   2011   
                       Europe  US      Europe US
Bikes    YTD           10.0    23.0    12.0   34.0
         YTD v prev    10%     8%      20%    45% 
Carpets  YTD           1.0     1.0     2.0    1.0
         YTD v prev    100%    100%    100%   0%
```

What structure would you use in R to represent this ?